# Python Regex: Matching a phrase regardless of intermediate spaces

Tags: python, regex, whitespace

Given a phrase in a given line, I need to be able to match that phrase even if the words have a different number of spaces in the line.

Thus, if the phrase is `"the quick brown fox"` and the line is `"the           quick      brown        fox jumped over the lazy dog"`, the instance of `"the           quick      brown        fox"` should still be matched.

The method I already tried was to replace all instances of whitespace in the line with a regex pattern for whitespace, but this doesn't always work if the line contains characters that aren't treated as literal by regex.

Comment: To clarify, the program in which this will be implemented is designed to handle an arbitrarily large number of lines, so I need to be able to pattern match given any line and a series of words that appear in that line.

Comment: Please add more sample data. If you only show a single line, we cannot see a broader pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import re

pattern = r'the\s+quick\s+brown\s+fox'
text = 'the           quick      brown        fox jumped over the lazy dog'

match = re.match(pattern, text)
print(match.group(0))
```

The output is:

```
the           quick      brown        fox
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to generalize this solution so that I don't have to make a regex pattern for each line by hand? The program I'm working on iterates over many lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex. Check [here](https://regex101.com/r/rFCg9p/1)

```
(the\s+quick\s+brown\s+fox)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I probably wasn't specific enough, but there's more than one line, so the solution needs to be applicable to any line.

Comment: More than one line. Are the same sentences?

Comment: The line and the phrase are different every time.

Comment: Can you provide the example of the phrases 3 to 5 more? So we can recognize the pattern. Do you want to get the first 4 words in each phrase?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the given string by white spaces and join them back by a white space, so that you can then compare it to the phrase you're looking for:

```
s = "the           quick      brown        fox"
' '.join(s.split()) == "the quick brown fox" # returns True
```

Answer (score 0):

for the general case:

1. replace each sequence of space characters in only one space character.
2. check if the given sentence is sub string of the line after the replacement

   ```
   import re

   pattern = "your pattern"

   for line in lines:
       line_without_spaces= re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', line)  
       # will replace multiple spaces with one space
       return pattern in line_without_spaces
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As your later clarified, you needed to match any line and series of words. To achieve this I added some more examples to clarify what the both proposed similar regexes do:

```
text = """the           quick      brown        fox
another line                    with single and multiple            spaces
some     other       instance     with        six                      words"""
```

#### Matching whole lines

The first one matches the whole line, iterating over the single lines

```
pattern1 = re.compile(r'((?:\w+)(?:\s+|$))+')
for i, line in enumerate(text.split('\n')):
    match = re.match(pattern1, line)
    print(i, match.group(0))
```

Its output is:

```
0 the           quick      brown        fox
1 another line                    with single and multiple            spaces
2 some     other       instance     with        six                      words
```

#### Matching whole lines

The second one matches single words and iterates of them one-by-one while iterating over the single lines:

```
pattern2 = re.compile(r'(\w+)(?:\s+|$)')
for i, line in enumerate(text.split('\n')):
    for m in re.finditer(pattern2, line):
        print(m.group(1))
    print()
```

Its output is:

```
the
quick
brown
fox

another
line
with
single
and
multiple
spaces

some
other
instance
with
six
words
```